# Kafka Serializer and Schema registery

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In my producer I have a property kafkaProducer.value.serializer and is set as org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.

I just want to know if schema registry is of same use or do these both serve different purpose?
For eg: Avro Serialization

Answer (score 0):

The Producer configuration includes mandatory serializers. This ( StringSerializer) is a default serializer for String data type. Kafka also includes serializers for String, Long, Double, Integer, and ByteArrays.

Both are used to serialize the data and store it in Kafka. Avro has a JSON like data model, but can be represented as either JSON or in a compact binary form. These are the following benefits of Avro Serialization.

```
Messages are highly efficient

Strong schema support

Schema versioning

Dynamic schema support

Different, but compatible, Reader and Writer versions allowed
Union types

Object container files can include schema along with encoded records
Support for serialization/deserialization with human-readable JSON
```

Complete information for this is available at following URL.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/avro-kafka-data/

https://www.codingblocks.net/programming/why-avro/

https://blog.cloudera.com/robust-message-serialization-in-apache-kafka-using-apache-avro-part-1/

[image]